Frida create instance of abstract java class and override function
Is it possible to create an instance of an abstract class and override functions just for the instance?
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public void OverrideCallback() {
    }
}

I would like to simulate this:
new AbstractClass() { 
            @Override
            public final OverrideCallback() {
                // ...
            }
        };

I tried the following, but as I expected it overrides the AbstractClass function for all instances.
const ac =  Java.use('AbstractClass');
const acInstance = ac.$new();
acInstance.OverrideCallback.implementation = function () {
    console.log('intercepted');
}
acInstance.OverrideCallback(); // prints intercepted
const acAnotherInstance = ac.$new();
acAnotherInstance.OverrideCallback(); // also prints intercepted


As a workaround you could prepare a smali file that contains a class that extends AbstractClass and implements OverrideCallback e.g. by an empty method. Make a dex file from that smali file and use Frida to load it into your process. Then you should be able to hook that newly created class.

Thanks for your input @Robert. I think I found a solution with Java.registerClass{superClass}. I'm currently testing it and will post an answer if it works

When I first read the frida docs, I didn't catch Java.registerClass. This is quite powerful and can also implement interfaces.
const DerivedClass = Java.registerClass({
    name: 'DerivedClass',
    superClass: [Java.use('AbstractClass')],
    methods: { 
        OverrideCallback() {
             console.log('intercepted');
        },
    }
});

const instance = DerivedClass.$new();
instance.OverrideCallback();

